# Laravel/HTML - Getting the assigned ID for every <input type = "hidden"> in each table row

Tags: php, html, laravel, input

I am trying to pass every ID retrieved from the database by getting them from every  field with a type of hidden for every table row. This is the picture of what I am currently doing:

[image]

I already assigned IDs on their respective  fields but every time submit the form it always retrieves the last ID which is ID 10. For example if I clicked the one of the radio button of second row which has to be an ID of 7 it will ALWAYS retrieve the last row's ID (10) instead of its corresponding ID which is 7.

```
@foreach($flights_depart as $flight)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $flight->flight_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ $flight->departure_schedule }}</td>
        <td>{{ $depart_source_country }}</td>
        <td>{{ $flight->arrival_schedule }}</td>
        <td>{{ $destination->country_name }}</td>

        @for($y=$counter1; $y<@count($first_durations); $y++)
            @php 
                $search = "0 Day";
                $position = strpos($first_durations[$y], $search); 

                if($position === 0){
                   $currentDuration = substr($first_durations[$y], 9);
                }else{
                   $currentDuration = $first_durations[$y];
                }
             @endphp
             @break;
         @endfor
         <td> {{ $currentDuration }} </td>
         <td> <!-- ECONOMY CLASS -->
             @php
                 $total_fare1 = intval($book_details['seat_qty'] * ($booking_types[0] + $destination->country_price));
                 echo "<center>PHP ". number_format($total_fare1, 2, '.', ',');
                 echo "<br>";
             @endphp
             <input type="radio" name="total_departure_fare" value="{{$total_fare1}}" required>   
         </td>
         <td> <!-- BUSINESS CLASS -->
            @php
                $total_fare2 = intval($book_details['seat_qty'] * ($booking_types[1] + $destination->country_price));
                echo "<center>PHP ". number_format($total_fare2, 2, '.', ',');
                                            echo "<br>";
            @endphp
            <input type="radio" name="total_departure_fare" value="{{$total_fare2}}" required>   
        </td>
        <td> <!-- FIRST CLASS -->
            @php
                $total_fare3 = intval($book_details['seat_qty'] * ($booking_types[2] + $destination->country_price));
                echo "<center>PHP ". number_format($total_fare3, 2, '.', ',');
                echo "<br>";
            @endphp
           <input type="radio" name="total_departure_fare" value="{{$total_fare3}}" required> 
       </td>
       <input type="hidden" value="{{$flight->flight_id}}" name="departure_flight_id"> //THIS IS FIELD THAT IS RESPONSIBLE FOR ASSIGNING IDS
    </tr>
    @php 
        $counter1++;
    @endphp


@endforeach
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Continue') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I already tried placing it outside the table row but it does not change anything. **How do I retrieve the right ID for each table row?**

Comment: Can you show the code for submitting the form? And clicking the radio button?

Comment: already added :)

Comment: what might be the cause of it?

Comment: As it is, ALL the hidden inputs are sent everytime regardless of the checkboxes. But the name of your hidden input is always the same, `departure_flight_id`, so it gets overwritten and only the last one is sent. What are you trying to achieve? What kind of request would you like to receive?